# eofExeption with objectstream and hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream, eofexception

so i have a problem with storing or loading a hashmap from an objectstream. The file is saved and i can see that it store some kind of information. the problem is when i try to read the hashmap it gives me an EOF error. thanks in advance for your help.

```
public synchronized void store(StoredObject storedObject) {

    try {
        String objectName = storedObject.getObject().getClass().getName();

        File file = new File(LOCAL_STORAGE_PATH + objectName);
        boolean isNewFile = !file.exists();


        output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        if (isNewFile) {
            localStorage = new HashMap<String, StoredObject>();
        } else {
            /////////////////////////
            ////does not work ///////
            /////////////////////////
            localStorage = (HashMap) input.readObject();
        }


        localStorage.put(storedObject.getKey(), storedObject);

        output.writeObject(localStorage);;
        output.flush();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(LocalServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "ioexception", ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LocalServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "class missmatch", ex);
    }
    finally{
         try {
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(LocalServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "could not close connection", ex1);
        }
    }

}
```

the error message:

java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2601)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1319)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at ServiceLayer.LocalServer.LocalServer.store(LocalServer.java:66)
    at ServiceLayer.LocalServer.LocalServerTEST.main(LocalServerTEST.java:17)

stuff i have tried:
make it syncronized. The object(StoredObject) and subobjects impliments serializable.

Answer (score 2):

You have your output and input code mixed together. You're creating the output and input streams at the same time. When you call `new FileOutputStream(file)`, it replaces the existing file, so when you try to read it, it's empty.

Move your output and input code into two different methods.